# FixedThreadPool threadcount and runtime

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I wrote a simple tool which checks some xmls (unmarshalling and content analyses) for content and writes a logfile per xml.

I have to check more than thousand files with about 2 MB / file. So the progress takes some time. Because there are no dependencies between my files I tried to do the work in different threads (no synchronized methods).

Unfortunately something with my ExecutorService seems to be wrong. I tried to use a fixedthreadpool Executorservice. But the runtime with 1 and 100 threads is hardly the same (as well as the cpu usage). Only if I use 1 Thread per file (files.size) the cpu usage is much higher (about 90 %) and the runtime is about 10 % of the original runtime.

I don’t understand why runtime and cpu usage with 1 thread is the same as with 100 threads.

```
package mycode;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Starter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    File config = new File(args[0]);
    Starter starter = new Starter(); 
    starter.work(config);
}

private void work(File config)
{
    Long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ConfigReader cr = new ConfigReader(config);
    cr.init();
    FileFinder ff = new FileFinder();
    List<File>files = ff.findfiles(cr.getParam("xmlfolder"));
    List<String>done = new ArrayList<String>();


    ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Integer.parseInt(cr.getParam("max.threadcount")));
    for (File aktuell : files)
    {
        es.execute(new Threadstarter(aktuell, cr.getParam("logoutput"), done)); 
    }



    es.shutdown();


    try {
        es.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Long end = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    BufferedWriter logwriter; 
    try {
        logwriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(cr.getParam("logoutput")).getAbsolutePath()+"/log.log"));
        for (String temp : done)
        {
            logwriter.write(temp);
            logwriter.newLine();
        }
        logwriter.write("Die Verarbeitung dauerte "+(end-start)/1000 +" Sekunden");
        logwriter.newLine();
        logwriter.write("Es wurden "+files.size()+" Dienststellen verarbeitet");
        logwriter.flush();
        logwriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

Comment: You are not able to find difference when you specify `max.threadcount` as 1 and when you specify this as 100? And can you provide a minimal reproducible code because looking at this code I think you should get X number of parallel processing threads where X = `max.threadcount`.

Comment: When you run with just one thread, how much time does the process spend doing computation and how much time does it spend doing I/O?  Your computer probably has more than one CPU, so adding more threads allows it to compute faster (up to the number of CPUs that you have), but if all of those files are on the same disk...  There is only one port for talking to the disk.  Adding more threads won't improve the I/O time at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no relation or not an easy one. It depends on the jobs the threads are doing. A program with one thread can consume 100% of CPU and a program with lots of threads can consume less.

If you are looking for an optimized relation between threads and job done, you must study your case, and possibly found an empiric solution.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.

As @hagrawal wrote, there is no difference between working with 1, 10 or 100 threads. Just if I use as much threads as I have files on my list, I have much more CPU usage (until the CPU becomes the bottleneck) and the whole progress needs about 10 % time. Unfortunately that needs a huge amount of memory and I am afraid, that it will cause a software crash with even more files in future.

I can’t imagine, that it might be an I/O problem. The raid 0 system of my machine should be able to do that without any effort. If my understanding of the problem is correct, it can’t be an I/O problem. Because if I/O is the bottleneck, the performance should not increase if the number of threads is equal to the number of files (in my case about 1000). Or is there something wrong in my mint?

Unfortunately the CPU usage is hardly identical with 1, 10 and 100 threads. So my impression is, that the progress starts with a fixed number of threads (as configured) and the executor service waits for all of them to be terminated, before it starts a new one. But my understanding was, that it starts a new thread, as soon as the first one is terminated and free?